# @render doesn't cause to load data from server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Data from router I'm trying to render inside another router is not loading, by data for main router is loaded.
When I directly going to a route which I'm trying to render then data is loaded.

Can find a way to debug this situation, appreciate you suggestions, guys!

P.S. I'm rendering by calling the render function

To clarify the question:

I have 2 routes

```
EmberTester.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  },
  isEditing: false,
  actions: {
    select: function(post) {
      this.render("external_users", {
        into: "users",
        outlet: "externalOutlet"
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
EmberTester.ExternalUsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('external_user');
  }
});
```

And I when I'm calling a `render` function in `select` action in `Users Route` it renders the template, but without the model I've defined in `ExternalUsersRoute`, and my *template* requires that data to be presented correctly.

Is there any way to have a hook which loads data for another router?

**Update**

Here is my router configuration:

```
EmberTester.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("users");
  return this.resource("external_users");
});

EmberTester.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  },
  actions: {
    select: function(post) {
      this.set('controller.content', this.store.find('external_user'));
      this.render("external_users", {
        into: "users",
        outlet: "externalOutlet"
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
});

EmberTester.ExternalUsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('external_user');
  }
});

EmberTester.externalUsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "users",
  userNameBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('controllers.users.external_user_id')
});

EmberTester.UsersController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ["external_users"],
  external_user_id: null
});
```

Here is my view for `users`

```
%h1 Feeds
.col-md-8
  .input-group
    %span.input-group-addon @
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="external_user_id" classNames="form-control" action="select" placeholder="feedname"}}
{{outlet externalOutlet}}        
%br
.col-md-8
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading header here
    .panel-body to be used as description
    %table.table.table-striped
      %tr
        %th ID
        %th Name
      = hb "each user in content" do
        %tr
          %td
            = hb 'user.id'
          %td
            = hb 'user.first_name'
            = hb 'user.last_name'
```

And here is my view for `External Users` [I not really sure my _external_users_ should be in content, but nevertheless there is no request to server on *render*]

```
.col-md-8 
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-picture External users    
    .panel-body
      .input-group
        %span.input-group-addon @
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="userName" classNames="form-control" action="select" placeholder="feedname"}}
      = hb "each external_user in content" do
        = hb 'external_user.username'
```

Comment: Ok, got it working before this.render had to call this.set('controller.content', this.store.find('entity')) But doesn't really like this way, is there are way to say that model has to be fetched from server aumatically?

Comment: Show some code plz. Your question is not understandable at all. Your comment looks like you are having some problems understanding the different hooks of Routes and their use.

Comment: @mavilein thanks for a suggestion! Added a code, please help me to understand Routes better

Comment: Can you show your router mapping and the 2 templates? Most of the times there is no need to call render manually.

Comment: @mavilein thank you very much for looking into my question! I've updated it with mapping and 2 templates

Comment: What kind of templating language is this? What should you App do? It seems like you want to take the id from the inputfield and show all external users associated to this id?

Comment: @mavilein it's a HAML, yes, that's correct, I need to lookup users from external system. Do you have any idea if my **external_users** router should return a model or it's behaviour is correct?